# What would be possible uses for finding minimum zone flatness in 3D or higher dimensions?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, computational-geometry

Let's start in 3D. Suppose $A\subset \Bbb R^3$ is a finite collection of points, the so-called *minimum zone flatness* is the minimised distance between two parallel planes that "sandwich" $A$ in between. And the *minimum zone* is the region sandwiched by such two planes.

[This article](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0010448517300337/1-s2.0-S0010448517300337-main.pdf?_tid=65adddec-cc30-11e7-aec2-00000aacb35d&acdnat=1510989578_c844db9a90a7536c7bf3d72be699310b) proposes a highly efficient algorithm to accomplish the task of finding the minimum zone and minimum zone flatness for large datasets. In the introduction part, the author says

> Flatness is one of the most fundamental geometric forms that
>   are used in manufacturing to measure the quality of a machined
>   surface.

Beyond this, however, I cannot think of any other situations in which finding the minimum zone of a dataset may be useful. And if we extend the task to higher dimensions ($\Bbb R^k, k\ge 4$), then I'm unable to imagine a single usage of finding such a minimum zone. Interestingly, though, finding the minimum zone seems to be an "opposite" task of finding the "maximum zone" formed by two separating planes in [support vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine).  But I don't see any way to relate it to SVM.

Could anybody enlighten me? Thanks!

Comment: Take coordinates on one of the plane and an orthogonal line. If the minimum zone is small, then all point will have coordinates $(a,b,\epsilon)$ for some small $\epsilon$. Depending on the application you may then be able to project the points to the plane without losing too much relevant information. Thereby reducing the dimension of the dataset by one. Note: I'm not sure if this is actually done.

Comment: @user2520938 Thanks! this sounds cool and is certainly extendible to higher dim. One potential pitfall of this approach, however, is that it's too sensible to outliers (this weakness is inherited from the definition of minimum zones, I think).